# Capture H.264/SVC encoded video in Android

Tags: android, video-capture, h.264, video-encoding, svc

Is it possible to capture H.264/SVC encoded video in Android?
Viceversa, is it possible to decode H.264/SVC encoded video in Android?
MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder class shows the following options for the video encoding.

int DEFAULT 
int H263
int H264
int MPEG_4_SP
int VP8

I am not sure H264 option   in Android support  SVC (Scalable Video Coding), even though H.264/SVC is an extension of H.264/AVC.

Thanks